# C copying to a string created from malloc

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I have this code:

```
char *name = malloc(strlen(args[1]) + 6);
strncpy(name, args[1], strlen(args[1]));
printf("%d\n", strlen(name));
```

Let's say `args[1]` is "hello" and so `strlen(args[1])` is 5.
After malloccing 11 bytes, I then copy 5 bytes of "Hello" (meaning I want to exclude the null terminating byte) to name.

But `strlen(name)` isn't 5. I get 8. Shouldn't it be 5 since you that's what you copied over?

Comment: The way `strlen` works is it counts characters until it sees the terminating null byte. Otherwise, how would it know you copied 5 characters? There's no special length value stored anywhere in the string, or it would require space wouldn't it? If you don't copy over the terminating null, it will keep counting until it does find a null. And then that's the length you'll get. The proper way to copy `args[1]` over to `name` is `strcpy(name, args[1]);` so that the entire string plus terminating null is copied.

Comment: "I get a number larger than 5." what number do you get?

Comment: You can't “exclude the null terminating byte”, it is a required part of the string.

Comment: Ok but I want to concat that string with another string. So I have to remove the null byte first right?

Comment: No. `strcat` takes care of the null bytes for you. So if you concatenate `str1` to `str2`, `strcat(str2, str1)` will locate the terminating null of `str2` and start copying `str1` at that location until it finds the terminating null of `str1`, and copies that, too, and stops. If you use the C string library, it just does the right thing with strings that terminate in null.

Comment: Ok thanks. Now if I want to use strncat(), should I do strncat(name, args[1], strlen(args[1]) + 1)); ?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `strncat`? You don't need to if you're concatenating the whole string. Just use `strcat(name, args[1])`.

Comment: Security right? I'm talking about strncpy not strncat

Comment: Can you be more specific what security issue you're worried about? `strncat(name, args[1], strlen(args[1]) + 1)` is going to do the same thing as `strcat(name, args[1])`. You're confusing things Your last comment was talking about `strncat`. Same logic applies to `strcpy`.

Comment: Buffer overflows when you copy more than the destination string can hold.  And I'm talking about strnCPY not strnCAT

Comment: `strncpy` will copy the 5 chars and will *not* have room to add a terminating nul char. As it is, the `name` string will not be nul-terminated, and using it as an argument to strlen is undefined behavior.

Comment: Right buffer overflows. So if your `strlen` calculates the wrong length of the string because you didn't use a terminating null, what do you think `strncpy(name, args[1], strlen(args[1])+1)` is going to do? It does the same thing as `strcpy(name, args[1])`.

Comment: ok then I could just do `strncpy(name, strlen(args[1]) + 1);` But I just realized that its not necessary in this case because I malloc based on `strlen` of the user's input anyways

Comment: No. You can't do `strncpy(name, strlen(args[1]) + 1)`. It's a syntax error since `strncpy` requires two string pointers and a length. Let me repeat for the third time: `strcpy(name, args[1])`. It does the same thing as `strncpy(name, args[1], strlen(args[1])+1)`.

Comment: Sorry I meant to stay `strncpy(name, args[1], strlen(args[1]) + 1);` If I'm concerned about buffer overflows then I would use this. But since I'm already allocating space based on strlen of the user's input in `name` anyways, I dont need strncpy and can just use strcpy

Comment: It's up to you to `malloc` enough space for your `strcpy`. If you do `name = malloc(strlen(args[1]) + 1)`, that would be enough room to do `strcpy(name, args[1])`.

Comment: Correct, and that seems like a more cleaner implementation

Comment: Certainly if `name = malloc(strlen(args[1])+1)` would work, then certainly your original `name = malloc(strlen(args[1])) + 6)` would work. It just happens to allocate more space than you require.

Comment: When you use `strncpy` and `strncat`, the limit should be based on the size of the **destination**, not the **source**. That's how you prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: Yeah I plan on concatenating with another string later

Comment: If you want to concatenate another string to `name` later, you **must** allocate enough room in `name` to accommodate what you plan. That's up to you, and that's how you prevent an overflow. You can allocate a number of bytes to `name` and later check the length of anything you plan to concatenate before you do so if you want to be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code uses `strncpy` incorrectly. The `strncpy` function is an unsafe version of `strcpy` and should be avoided;  using it correctly requires writing unnecessarily complicated code.

Instead you can write:

```
char *name = malloc(strlen(args[1]) + 6);
strcpy(name, args[1]);
printf("%zu\n", strlen(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you exclude the null-terminating byte, you don't have a string. So you can't pass it to `strlen` and expect to get sensible results.

Answer (score 0):

Copy like this instead:

```
strncpy(name, args[1], strlen(args[1]) + 1);
                                      ^^^^
```

or specify *n* = length of `name` - 1.

The string "hello" takes 6 bytes: 5 letters and the null terminator. When you tell `strncpy` to copy at most 5 bytes (that's what `strlen(args[1])` in your code does) then it will do just that: copy the letters and it won't write the null terminator.

That means `name` is not a valid string, and calling `strlen(name)` is undefined behavior. In your case there just happens to be a zero byte so `strlen` returns 8.

In my opinion this behavior of `strncpy` is poor design, but that's the way it is.